# Java Gradle copy 2 different folders in one task

Tags: java, gradle

I use gradle-2.8 on java project in intelliJidea. I need to copy 2 different resources into 2 different folders.

I tried:

```
task copySubprojectLibs (type: Copy, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
    from (subprojects.jar) {
        into 'build/libs/lib'
    }

    from ('src/main/resources') {
        into 'build/libs/nosr/conf'
    }
}
```

Then tried:

```
task copySubprojectLibs (type: Copy, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
    from (subprojects.jar) into 'build/libs/lib'
    from ('src/main/resources') into 'build/libs/nosr/conf'
}
```

Then tried to remove dependsOn, type arguments, reorder lines, etc, but I always get

```
> No value has been specified for property 'destinationDir'.
```

What I have to do to copy 2 resources to 2 different folders? In one task or in 2 tasks, this stuff doesn't work in two tasks either. But simple copy in one line and one task works. How to do that in one task? It's a simple problem, why gradle that tricky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Copy task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) is configured with a [CopySpec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html), which only allows one destination directory.

Consider this approach instead:

```
task copySubprojectLibsA (type: Copy, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
    from subprojects.jar 
    into 'build/libs/lib'
}

task copySubprojectLibsB (type: Copy, dependsOn: subprojects.jar) {
    from 'src/main/resources'
    into 'build/libs/nosr/conf'
}

task copySubprojectLibs(dependsOn: ["copySubprojectLibsA","copySubprojectLibsB"])
```

An alternative is to use the Ant Builder contained in Gradle:

```
task copySubprojectLibs (dependsOn: subprojects.jar) << {
    files(subprojects.jar).each { 
        ant.copy(file: it.absolutePath, todir: "build/libs/lib")
    }
    ant.copy(todir: "build/libs/nosr/conf") {
        fileset(dir: "src/main/resources")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I think it might not be that tricky in gradle

Comment: To be  complete, I have added an example using the Ant Builder, in case readers prefer that style. Gradle is tremendously flexible and offers several alternatives to problems.